# CVE-2022-31159 in spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging 2.2.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

Can someone let me know if `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging` version 2.2.6 is affected by [CVE-2022-31159](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-31159) due to the dependency on `aws-java-sdk-s3` version `1.11.792` ?

Dependency tree

```
+- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-core:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.792:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.792:compile
```

2.2.6 is the latest version of `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging`. Is there any plan to bump up the version of `aws-java-sdk-s3` to at-least 1.12.261 in `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging` so that CVE tracker tools do not flag this artifact?

Is `spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging`, version 2.2.6 compatible with `aws-java-sdk-s3` version 1.12.261 so that I can upgrade the version of aws-java-sdk-s3 in my pom?